# A responsive CSS grid for high-res screens

Tags: html, css, frameworks

I am using [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) now and like how it manages screens of different sizes but its max width is 960px. Please recommend me some responsive CSS framework that is created and tested for screens up to 1920px width. I know I can update existing Skeleton instance for my needs but I'd like to try something ready-to-use.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most grid frameworks don't tend to go right up to 1920, it's up to you to extend them the last bit. Check out these two for alternatives to Skeleton though:

http://www.cssgrid.net

http://www.tinyfluidgrid.com

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you can set a width as high as you want with [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com). Personally, I never go this high up, but see how it fares. It should size down appropriately. Foundation does come with a lot of extras, but you can opt out of them on the download page.

...actually, I just did a quick download, with just the responsive CSS and main styles and a couple of the pre-made HTML templates, and sized the window up. Works pretty well, I think. I set the max-width at 1920px. Figure out how many columns you need, etc. and test it out.